# WBADMIN addtarget DISKID error

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

trying to add a drive to a Win2008R2ENT backup set using the command line, but the following command wants to use DISK_01 as the new ID, surely I want this to be DISK_02 as DISK_01 already exists on another external drive?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! I Hit Yes, and it then labelled it as Disk_02.